# What how I parse an html string with beautifulsoup that has inner tags within text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a the following html content in a variable and need a way to read the text from the html by removing the inner tags

`html=<td class="row">India (ASIA) (<a href="/asia/india">india</a>&nbsp;–&nbsp;<a href="/asia/india">photos</a>)</td>`

I just want to extract the string `India (ASIA)` out of this with BeautifulSoup. Is it possible or should I resort to use regular expressions for this.

Answer (score 4):

This is one possible way using beautifulsoup, by extracting text content before child element `<a>` :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<td class="row">India (ASIA) (<a href="/asia/india">india</a>&nbsp;–&nbsp;<a href="/asia/india">photos</a>)</td>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
result = soup.find("a").previousSibling
print(result.decode('utf-8'))
```

**output :**

```
India (ASIA) (
```

<sub>tweaking the code further to remove trailing `(` from `result` should be straightforward</sub>